# @PreDestroy not being called in SpringBoot WAR application deployed in Wildfly container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having trouble with a Spring Boot (1.5.6) application in which I want to perform some cleanup upon shutdown.  My Boot application is packaged as a `war` and is deployed in a Wildfly 10 application container.

I've attempted the following:

```
@Component
public class Cleanup {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Cleanup.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rabbitConnection")
    private Connection rmqConnection;

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownConnection() throws JMSException{
        System.out.println("************************SHUTTING DOWN************************");
        rmqConnection.close();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        log.warn("POST CONSTRUCT");
    }

}
```

I see Spring registering the hooks:

```
2017-09-05 12:14:15,146 DEBUG [org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]     Registered init method on class [org.jms.Cleanup]: org.springframework.beans.factory
.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement@a1ab9f17
2017-09-05 12:14:15,146 DEBUG [org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]     Registered destroy method on class [org.jms.Cleanup]: org.springframework.beans.fact   ory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement@5d82edd4
```

I also see the "POST CONSTRUCT" in the log file, but the `@PreDestroy` method is never called, even though I've disabled/undeployed the application in Wildfly.

I then figured I would try adding an ApplicationListener, but I'm not sure how do to this when the application is bootstrapped by the `org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener` and not the `main()` method.

I realize I could use a ContextListener, but that defeats my purpose a little of making this a general-style application.  I was hoping to assign an ApplicationListener, but given that I don't have control over the creation of the SpringApplication (happens in the `SpringBootContextLoaderListener`, that didn't work.

My last attempt was to create an `@EventListener`, but that failed to fire as well:

```
@Component
public class Cleanup {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Cleanup.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rabbitConnection")
    private Connection rmqConnection;

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("************************STOPPING CONTEXXT************************");
        log.warn("STOPPING CONTEXT");
        try {
            rmqConnection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The log show that it was registered:

```
2017-09-05 12:28:49,678 DEBUG [org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor]     1 @EventListener methods processed on bean 'cleanup': {public void org.jms.Cleanup.handleConte   xtRefresh(org.springframework.context.event.ContextStoppedEvent)=@org.springframework.context.event.EventListener(value=[], classes=[], condition=)}
```

The logs also show that the context is being closed:

```
2017-09-05 12:39:42,723 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow]     WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2017-09-05 12:39:43,335 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]     WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2017-09-05 12:41:22,771 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow]     WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2017-09-05 12:41:22,776 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet]     Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2017-09-05 12:41:23,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment]     WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: jms-0.0.1-SN
APSHOT.war) in 545ms
2017-09-05 12:41:23,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]     WFLYDS0018: Deployment jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war was previously deployed by t
his scanner but has been undeployed by another management tool. Marker file C:\dev\tmp\jboss-eap-7.0.0\standalone\deployments\jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.
undeployed is being added to record this fact.
2017-09-05 12:41:23,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]     WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
```

My Java Config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class JmsReceiver {

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new BeanFactoryDestinationResolver(springContextBeanFactory));
        factory.setConcurrency("1");
        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RMQConnectionFactory conn = new RMQConnectionFactory();
        conn.setUsername("test");
        conn.setPassword("test");
        conn.setHost("localhost");
        conn.setPort(5672);
        conn.setVirtualHost("test");
        conn.setOnMessageTimeoutMs(2000);
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I'm a bit at a loss now what else I can try to register a shutdown hook.  I've even tried implementing `DisposableBean` but to no avail.

What is the recommended mechanism at this point?  Is this a container issue?  How can I add a shutdown listener to my Spring Boot webapp?  Am I stuck if I am using the legacy `org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener`?

I created a sample application to show the problems with the events at https://github.com/benze/springbootevents.

Comment: Why do you need the cleanup? Spring Boot, when using the auto-config, should already clean up those things for you. Why are you even using the `SpringBootContextLoaderListener` and not a `SpringBootServletInitializer`? Wildfly supports that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need to run this same app in both Wildfly and JBoss 4.2 (which is Servlet 2.5).  If I don't do a cleanup, my JMS connection remains open, and I want to ensure that it gets closed.  Is there an advantage to the `SpringBootServletInitializer` as opposed to the `SpringBootContextLoaderListener`?  I tried to follow the Spring Boot Legacy docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-servlet-2-5).

Comment: Then you have something strange in your setup... As that should be closed normally, looks like you are fighting the framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't think I have anything particularly strange.  It is fairly straight forward.  I have edited my question with my config class.  Although I agree - I feel light I'm fighting the framework.  I've had to do something quite ugly to get around the issue, which I really don't want to use in production.

Comment: Also an `ApplicationListener` is just another bean implementing that interface. However the fact that you don't receive any callbacks at all is weird in the first place. Is it actually being stopped when you stop/undeplpoy the app in wildly?

Comment: @M.Deinum I see the jboss/undertow logs indicating that it is.  I've added them to the question as well.

Comment: What I actually meant is does the application actually receive a nice callback to be shutdown (if not it will not stop).

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure; any way to see/determine that?  Who/what/how triggers the shutdown callback?

Comment: The `SpringBootContextLoaderListener` due to it being a `ServletContextListener`. Instead of writing your own component you might want to try and wrap the `ConnectionFactory` in a `SingleConnectionFactory` or `CachingConnectionFactory` from Spring. This already takes care of closing connections (and saves you from writing an additional component).

Comment: What I also don't get is you are auto wiring a connection but your connection is not a bean... So how does that get injected in the first place?! Looks like you are closing a connection that isn't the same as the one used by the listener container.

Comment: We use PreDestroy and it works just fine.  Though we do not use it with Widfly nor JBOSS.  What we noticed is that when our microservice gets a TERM signal, then the PreDestory is called.  Because we use executable jar files, there is never the situation where we turning off the microservice while leaving the web container running.

Comment: @M.Deinum Indeed; I'm fighting the framework on several different fronts.  I was hoping that behind the scenes, Spring was creating a connection bean that I could autowire into my cleanup bean.  I didn't know about the `SingleConnectionFactory()` - I'm trying that right now.

Comment: @M.Deinum Not working with the `SingleConnectionFactory()` either.  To make things worse, I am injecting the SCF into my ContextListener, hoping to be able to do a `SCF.getConnection().close()`, but that doesn't do the job either.  Even though it is a single connection, each call to `getConnection()` seems to create a different proxy to the same connection, but consequently, the `close()` only works on the proxy used to start the connection.  So I'm left with no way to retrieve the connection and shut it down.

Comment: If you use `SingleConnectionFactory` you don't need your custom component anymore, the `SimpleConnectionFactory` takes care of closing the opened connection. Calling close on the connection got from the `SingleConnectionFactory` will do nothing as the `close` is suppressed (using a proxy). Just remove your component as the `SingleConnectionFactory` will close the connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum Amazingly enough, none of the listeners are being fired, so consequently, the SingleConnectionFactory doesn't shut down the connections either.  I created a sample app at https://github.com/benze/springbootevents to show the problem.  I don't know if this is a SpringBoot bug of a Wildfly bug.

Comment: I guess this is a WildFly issue (you can probably test is with another container like Tomcat) and/or how you are stopping the application.